# C#, Amazon Lambda Functions and Nuget packages compatability

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am porting my c# code to AWS and plan on moving the  POST and GET requests to the database I was using prior from the client side to the back end on Lambda. I currently am implementing `httpwebresponse` and other `System.net` references. Can Lambda make use of these as well, and could it also work with other nuget packages like Newtonsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda runs .NET Core 1.0 so any nuget packages that support that will run.

Comment: for what its worth Lambda now also runs .NET core 2.0 https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/01/aws-lambda-supports-c-sharp-dot-net-core-2-0/

Comment: and .Net Core 2.1